Parent loaders not running in nested routes with mixed naming
I have the following nested routes in Remix:

overview.$categorySlug.tsx
overview.$categorySlug.$subCategorySlug.tsx
overview.$categorySlug.$subCategorySlug.progress.tsx
overview.$categorySlug.$subCategorySlug.disclosure.tsx
overview.carbon-accounting.$subCategorySlug.disclosure.tsx

All of them have a loader.
Results:

/overview/esrs/e1-4/disclosure → parent loaders run
/overview/carbon-accounting/waste/progress → parent loaders run
/overview/carbon-accounting/waste/disclosure → parent loaders DO NOT RUN

Do I need to duplicate my route files so I also have:

overview.carbon-accounting.tsx
overview.carbon-accounting.$subCategorySlug.tsx

…in order for parent loader to run?
